# Unable to call Graph API in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

net core application. I am trying to call Graph API in my application. Below is my code. This is the policy I  applied on top of Controller.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "APGroupsOnly")]
```

Below policy I added in startup.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("APGroupsOnly", policy =>
           policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupsCheckRequirement("YourGroupID")));
});
```

I am trying to hit apis from swagger. Below is my swagger config.

```
"ClientId": "my client id",
"ClientSecret": "my client secrete",
"AuthorizationUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/myid/oauth2/authorize",
"TokenUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/myid/oauth2/token"
```

Below is my MSGraphService.cs

```
public async Task<User> GetMeAsync(string accessToken)
{
    User currentUserObject;

    try
    {
        PrepareAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);
        currentUserObject = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
     }
     catch (ServiceException e)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine("We could not fetch details of the currently signed-in user: " + $"{e}");
         return null;
     }

    return currentUserObject;
}

private void PrepareAuthenticatedClient(string accessToken)
{
    if (graphServiceClient == null)
    {
        // Create Microsoft Graph client.
        try
        {
            graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
                        });
                    }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Could not create a graph client {ex}");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my GroupsCheckHandler

```
public class GroupsCheckHandler : AuthorizationHandler<GroupsCheckRequirement>
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IMSGraphService graphService;
    public GroupsCheckHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IMSGraphService MSGraphService)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        this.graphService = MSGraphService;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, GroupsCheckRequirement requirement)
    {
        var accessToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        User me = await graphService.GetMeAsync(accessToken);
    }
}
```

Whenever I check execute, I get the following error.

> We could not fetch details of the currently signed-in user: Status Code: Unauthorized
>       Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
>       Message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

Below is my startup file.

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            azureActiveDirectoryOptions = configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Get<AzureActiveDirectoryOptions>();
            swaggerUIOptions = configuration.GetSection("Swagger").Get<SwaggerUIOptions>();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        private readonly AzureActiveDirectoryOptions azureActiveDirectoryOptions;
        private readonly SwaggerUIOptions swaggerUIOptions;
        //
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddTransient<IMSGraphService, MSGraphService>();
            services
               .AddAuthentication(o =>
               {
                   o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

               })
               .AddJwtBearer(o =>
               {
                   o.Authority = azureActiveDirectoryOptions.Authority;

                   o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {

                       ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                       {
                          azureActiveDirectoryOptions.AppIdUri,
                          azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId
                       },
                       ValidateIssuer = true,
                       ValidateAudience = true,
                       ValidIssuer = "https://myorg.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/default",
                       RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role
                   };
               });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {

                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1); ;

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
                {
                    Type = "oauth2",
                    Flow = "implicit",
                    AuthorizationUrl = swaggerUIOptions.AuthorizationUrl,
                    TokenUrl = swaggerUIOptions.TokenUrl,
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {"Read", "13469a45-a2ea-45a1-96e7-6580f57b6e30/.default" }
                    }
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                        { "oauth2", new[] { "readAccess", "writeAccess" } }
                });
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("APGroupsOnly", policy =>
                       policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupsCheckRequirement("YourGroupID")));
            });
            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, GroupsCheckHandler>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
                c.OAuthClientId(swaggerUIOptions.ClientId);
                c.OAuthClientSecret(swaggerUIOptions.ClientSecret);
                c.OAuthRealm(azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId);
                c.OAuthAppName("Swagger");
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
                c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "resource", azureActiveDirectoryOptions.AppIdUri } });
            });
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the passed access token is not valid. You can check the access token at  [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) or [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to validate if token is valid to create the `GraphServiceClient`object and contains the graph scope.

Comment: Could you tell me how you get access token?

Comment: Hi Jim Xu. Access token is valid. I tested in jwt.io.

Comment: I am getting access token through swagger. I have added my startup file above.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you can use the access token to call the graph api in the postman? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman

Comment: Yes I can get access token. I already have setup for this. Whenever I use swagger, I get proper token.

Comment: Do you mean that the access token is right and you can use the access token to call  the graph API in the client(such as postman)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201484/discussion-between-niranjan-and-jim-xu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger is used to test your web api , so you can add `scope` to access your web api which protected by Azure AD :

```
Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
{      
    { "api://XXXXX/accessApi","api://XXXXX/accessApi"}
}
```

Clicking `Authorize` button in swagger and after user authenticated and get access token for your web api , you can test your web api in swagger  . But the access token is for accessing web api that the `Audience` is your web api's name/url , it can't be used to make Microsoft Graph api calls . They are different resource so you need to obtain two tokens .

If you web api needs to make an authenticated request to the downstream web API (Microsoft Graph )  on behalf of user , you can use [OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) .

Another choice is your web api call Microsoft Graph with their own identity - use [OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) to get token for accessing Microsoft Graph API . And [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth) is code sample which using Microsoft Graph sdk .